# How to get rid of #DIV/0! in excel...need non-geek response

Tags: excel

I have searched the web for help in this issue, only to come across countless replies that simply throw a page long code up and expect us common folk to understand wtf they are talking about. So here I am, searching for someone who can guide me through this process like I am a toddler and not just reply with a link to some page-long code. I realize there is code involved, but I am not interested in a page long code for something that has to be much simpler. I simply want to remove these values from the rows, not do any math on the rows or anything. Whatever code you send me, please explain exactly what each set of cells means and how that is supposed to be input by me. Thanks for helping a dinosaur.

Comment: That is of no help...I I have no clue what that means or what/where that needs to be input. I have already pasted the function to values only so there is no function left on the sheet and i don't want to do them all over again. I need to fix this the way they are. Again...you're not treating me like a toddler when you need to.

Comment: Thanks...that's simple enough. I told you I was a dinosaur, :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to divide something 0.
if you use this here in the Total column, =IFERROR(A2/B2, "") you will get a blank cell in place of that error.

```
     A    |　 B    |TOTAL (A/B) |
     1    |   0    |            |
     2    |   1    |      2     |
     3    |   2    |     1.5    |
     4    |   3    | 1.333333333|
```

Puttin this in the total column and double clicking the little green square will copy this to all the cells below. If you still need clarification just comment.
[image]

instead of the empty space if you can add anything in the place of the error. Like =IFERROR(A2/B2,"THIS IS AN ERROR!!") and if there are any of those error bugs "this is an error" will replace it.

Comment: That won't work either. I would need to still have the "A2/B2" columns on the sheet for that to work, and those are gone...there are 22 columns with over 400 rows for each that are all totals that have been moved over from where they were calculated. I need to do this within one column...not using columns with values used to get these totals because those are not there anymore.

Comment: That is the kind of information you need to put into your question. It is hard to give you some answer without some context.